# CMD - DOS Instant Answer

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've been using the DOS code for Windows before and I want to figure out the way where you can enter in a response and it will instantly reply to that response.
I used to use sequences such as:

```
set /a LLevel1_2=Blank
set /p LLevel1_2=
if %LLevel1_2%==1 goto Level1_3
```

The problem was that the user has to press 'enter' after typing in their answer.
I thought of using:

```
choice /c abcd /t 5 /d d
if %errorlevel%==4 goto Menu ELSE goto Part2
```

That lists the potential answers rather than just being blank from:

```
set /p LLevel1_2=
```

Please reply and I appreciate any help you can offer.

Also, a bonus if you can make it 'Caps Lock Sensitive'.

Comment: What is your question?  This doesn't make sense in that context: `That lists the potential answers rather than just being blank from:`

Comment: maybe you are looking for `choice`' switch `/n`?

Answer (score 0):

```
choice /n /CS /c abcd /t 5 /d d
if %errorlevel%==4 goto Menu ELSE goto Part2
```

try this before saying it is the same as your other idea .